# time_since() php function

Tags: php

do i need to include something to use time_since() function in php 5 or is has it been replace?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952361/date-time-convert-to-time-since-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It doesn't look like that function ever existed in PHP](http://au.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=time_since&lang=en). Do you mean [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) ?

However, you can get the time since an event like so...

```
$timeSince = time() - strtodate('last Saturday');
```

You can also use the object `DateTime`.

```
$now = new DateTime();

$timeSince = $now->diff(new DateTime('last Saturday'), TRUE);
```

Note that [`diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method wasn't introduced until PHP 5.3.

Comment: if i'm using a unix timestamp can that be put in the place if last Saturday in the above? Im looking for an output of 3 days 2 hours 15 mins ago

Comment: Nevermind it was a function i wrote and it was hidden inside my include file thx for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

[PHP working out time since the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465827/php-working-out-time-since-the-post)

If you're using PHP 5.3 or newer, you can take advantage of the new Date and Time classes added to PHP.

Specifically, DateTime has a diff method that returns a DateInterval class, which you can then format.